# Disable instant closing of TCP connections when interface or route becomes unavailable in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, ip, tcp

Whenever there is a brief glitch with my ethernet connection, Windows 10 instantly closes all of my TCP connections going over that interface.

Is there a way to change it so that the connections are held open for a little while so that they may resume when the interface comes back up a second later?

Anecdotal evidence points to this being the default behavior in Linux.